# Notification displays numbers, not the contentText

Tags: java, android, push-notification

My notification displays number, and not the text. My string is in cirylic letters, but that shouldn't be a problem. Also, could the length of a string matter? ContentText contains short 5 words.

Here is the snippet code for notification, which works, but only displays number:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, CHANNEL_ID) ;
    builder.setContentTitle(String.valueOf(R.string.appName));
    builder.setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);
    builder.setContentText(String.valueOf(R.string.wRevNow));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo ) ;
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID) ;
    return builder.build();
```

And here is what I get:

[image: notification pic]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `String.valueOf(R.string.appName)` where `R.string.appName` is a unique integer identifying the specific resource and `String.valueOf` casts the `integer value` to `string` and thereby numbers sliding in your notification,instead try the following

```
// code remains same

builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.appName));

builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.wRevNow));

//rest of the logic remains same
```

Comment: sure mate, if it solves accept the answer, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The R.string resource package contains int values, they represent the string in the app's resources. String.valueOf() returns only the string representation of that int (id). The getString(id: Int) method is used from a context to access them. Your code would look like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, CHANNEL_ID) ;
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.appName));
    builder.setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);
    builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.wRevNow));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo ) ;
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID) ;
    return builder.build();
```